# Need Expertise with Gantt Chart in Excel

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

All, I am trying to create a Gantt chart in excel but have some issues with the End Date as chart is not capturing the end date month showed in the pic. I have a start and end date and I would like to show the progress in Months only.
Here is the formula I am using `=AND(D$2>=$D15,D$2<=$E15+1)` where `D2 = Date`, `D15 = start Date` and `E15= End Date`. 
The chart only works if the end date is last day of the month.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first day of the corresponding months for start and end date in the comparisons.

To make date the first day of the month find the day through `DAY` formula subtract from the date and add 1. I hope this solves your problem. And please check the figure below.

For those who are looking for an almost VBA-free solution for their monthly termed Gannt charts, be sure to look at [Dad's Onion web site](https://excel.dadsonion.com/2019/04/data-bars-unleashed-colours-gantt-charts-and-more./) **Data bars unleashed - colours, gannt charts and more** article. There is a solution for shading cells partially in Gannt charts using conditional formatting. This solution is very useful for monthly or weekly termed Gannt charts.

[image: Gannt chart]

Comment: Thanks! But it seems like the issue is with the way I am showing months. I am using formula =EOMONTH(D2,0)+1 and =EOMONTH(E2,0)+1 all the way to the end and its not capturing the last month as stated above.

Comment: In your original question, you could have been more informative about the fact you are using EOMONTH so that we could offer you a solution with that function.